# Show & hide the navigation bar sencha touch 2

Tags: sencha-touch-2, navigationbar

In my app i have a navigationView with 1 item (a list) and the setting 'navigationBar: false'.

This is because in my listpanel i have a toolbar with a slidenavigation in it. All good.

However, when i tap on an item in the list, i push the next view, and then the navigationBar is of course still gone, but i want it on that view to be visible to have the back button and i have an other issue , when i click on the item , i have 2 windows opened the first one contain the name in the menu & then the second contains data ,
here is my fiddle : 
http://www.senchafiddle.com/#S7B5o#zNyZ9

Ps:i used the ux slidenavigation from this link :

https://github.com/wnielson/sencha-SlideNavigation

Thank u so much .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to watch for `push` and `back` events of your `navigationView`

```
Ext.define('Yourapp.controller.YourNavigationViewController', {
    extend: 'Ext.app.Controller',
    config: {
        refs: {
            nview: '#navview',// <-- your Ext.NavigationView with id 'navview' ;)
            nbar: '#navbar'// <-- navigationBar of your Ext.NavigationView
        },
        control: {
            nview: {
                push: 'onPush',
                back: 'onBack'
            }
        }
    },
    onPush: function() {
        this.getNavbar().setHidden(false);
    },
    onBack: function() {
        this.getNavbar().setHidden(true);
    }
});
```

Comment: It worked for me, but listening the events in nbar instead of nview.